# Solving recurrence $T(n) = T(n - 1) + n$ with substitution method

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relation

How can I solve the following recurrence $T(n) = T(n - 1) + n$ with the substitution method?
I guess the solution is $\Theta(n^2)$ I try to demonstrate $O(n^2)$:
$$T(n) \leq O(n^2) \\  \leq c(n-1)^2+n \\ \leq cn^2+c-2cn+n$$
How can i continue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can prove easily in induction, that $T(n)=c + \sum_{i=1}^n i$. Assume correctness for $n$, we will prove for $n+1$. Clearly, $T(n+1)=T(n)+(n+1)=c + n+1 + \sum_{i=1}^n i = c 
+ \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} i$.

A nice result you are probably familiar with, if you learned about [arithmetic progression series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression), is that $\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Thus, $T(n) = c + \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = \Theta(n^2)$

Answer (score 0):

$$T(n)=T(n-1)+n=\\=T(n-2)+(n-1)+n=\\=\cdots=\\
=T(1)+2+\cdots+(n-1)+n =\\= T(1) + \frac{n(n+1)}{2}-1 \in \Theta(n^2)$$

Answer (score 0):

c + n - 2cn is always negative for c , n >1 so T(n) < cn2